# Does MySQL support querying for the current running transaction id

Tags: mysql, postgresql, transaction

PostgreSQL supports retrieving the current running transaction id using a query like this:

```
select txid_current();
```

Does MySQL have any such equivalent?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? PostgreSQL provides that facility, but I'd be looking suspiciously at any application I saw using it. It's mostly an internal / debug feature, though there are some uses for it in HA/replication and DTX.

Comment: For debugging purposes, just as you said. I'd like to log it along with all the queries the ORM tool generates, to group them afterwards and provide a clue into what happens when some long lived transaction gets stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with MySQL 5.7, you can see the current transactions in the performance schema.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-transactions-current-table.html

Now, to find out the `THREAD_ID` of the current connection, use

```
SELECT THREAD_ID FROM performance_schema.threads
  WHERE PROCESSLIST_ID = CONNECTION_ID()
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/threads-table.html

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know which one is my current running transaction, associated to my current database connection?

Comment: Perhaps `CURRENT_USER()` and/or `CONNECTION_ID()`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how this would be more useful than just `CONNECTION_ID()` ... but the InnoDB transaction ID (shown in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`) is available using this:

```
SELECT trx_id 
  FROM information_schema.innodb_trx 
 WHERE trx_mysql_thread_id = CONNECTION_ID();
```

This is available in MySQL 5.5 and up (and possibly with the InnoDB plugin on 5.1), but transactions don't become visible here until your transaction has actually had some kind of interaction with InnoDB.